# Alert Dialog box selects positive button implicitly.

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am developing an application which has an alert dialog box in it. I want that the alert dialog box selects the positive button implicitly without interaction from user. It selects the positive button and automatically performs the actions set for positive button.

Is it possible?

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286135/android-alert-dialog-and-set-positive-button

Comment: what do you mean by select the positive manually

Comment: if app itself selects the positive button then what is the use of alert box in your app.

Comment: @Abd El-Rahman El-Tamawy;@Naveen i want just to open the activity directly which is opened after the positive click of alert dialog. Just to automate the process.

Comment: @user3346325, Naveen is right. I have edit my answer showing you how to call the activity from the positive button. Check it out

Comment: My app is using a using a custom listener which is responsible for transfer of data within activities and it can only be available using predefined events of that listener and alert dialog is invoked in an event of the listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible... we use it to execute the positive button handler after a countdown.

```
alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
```

But don't use this as immediate action, in that case, just perform the action without the dialog.

Based on what I understand is your use-case (doing stuff in the background of showing the dialog, then doing the positive action if the user does not respond when all of the "stuff" is done), it would look something like this:

```
class YourListener extends SomeListener {
    private alertDialog = null;

    public onSomeEvent(Event e) {
        alertDialog = createAlertDialog();
        alertDialog.show();

        // Do stuff

        if(alertDialog.isShowing()) {
            alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ya that is right way but I need to use dialog because it is invoked in an event of a listener.

Comment: Awesome. Please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it helped you; it's an important part of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the `AlertDialog` and customize all its feature like `title`, `actions` .. etc

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)//Disable back button action
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // Your positive action
                                            Intent i = new Intent(context, activity.class);
                                            startActivity(i); 
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // Your negative action
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```