# Cancel button in dialog box is not working when using radio button inside dialog box

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

> Cancel and Ok button in Dialog box is not working when using radio button inside dialog box.

```
public void bookappointment()
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bridaldialogbox, null);
    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
    final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
    alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    final EditText userstatus=(EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.choosen);
    address = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.address);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) promptView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            position = radioGroup.indexOfChild(promptView.findViewById(checkedId));
            position1 = radioGroup.indexOfChild(promptView.findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    userstatus.setText("Home");
                    bridal_status = userstatus.getText().toString();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    userstatus.setText("Mahal");
                    bridal_status = userstatus.getText().toString();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    Button ok_buy = (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.ok_bridal);
    ok_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button no_cancel = (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_bridal);
    no_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

> Am using the same dialog in functionality in some other place also there its worked fine but now when am using radio button its not working good after clicking the button for 5 or 6 times only the dialog box is dismissing

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use alert.setPositiveButton() and alert.setNegativeButton()?
Try those and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
alert.dismiss();
```

as the action in both your ok_buy and no_cancel buttons. Do you mean to do something affirmative in your ok_buy?

Comment: Yes i want to dismiss the dialog box when user clicks on both buttons

Answer (score 0):

As @Ruben2112 said look to this link ([Android alert dialog and set positive button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286135/android-alert-dialog-and-set-positive-button)) and set your positive and negative button. And in the negative button (cancel) try what Casey Murray said (`dialog.dismiss();` or `dialog.cancel()`)

Or maybe is because you set `alert.show()` before the set up the buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple [android dialog popup library](https://github.com/00ec454/pop). It is very simple to use on your activity.

Here is your working code

```
public void bookappointment(){
final AlertDialog dialog = Pop.on(getActivity())
   .with()
   .cancelable(false) //ignore if not needed
   .layout(R.layout.bridaldialogbox)
   .show(new Pop.View() {
       @Override
       public void prepare(View view) {
           final EditText userstatus=(EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.choosen);
           address = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
           radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
           radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                   position = radioGroup.indexOfChild(view.findViewById(checkedId));
                   position1 = radioGroup.indexOfChild(view.findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
                   switch (position) {
                       case 0:
                           userstatus.setText("Home");
                           bridal_status = userstatus.getText().toString();
                           break;
                       case 1:
                           userstatus.setText("Mahal");
                           bridal_status = userstatus.getText().toString();
                           break;
                   }
               }
               Button ok_buy = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ok_bridal);
               ok_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });

               Button no_cancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_bridal);
               no_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });             
           });
       }
   });
}
```

To make this work, include one time your gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.vistrav:pop:2.0'
}
```